# Using Google Docs in full screen mode without using file menu

Tags: google-docs

How can I reach the full screen mode of Google Documents without clicking View->Full Screen?

Is there a different URL perhaps that I can use or any other methods to get Google Docs to show the document at full screen?

Here's what it looks like in normal edit mode and window:

[image: GDocs in normal mode]

In full screen view:

[image: GDocs in full screen mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this via changing a URL parameter. The only other option is pressing `F11` to enter/exit full screen mode.

Note: Although it doesn't appear to be exactly the same as clicking `View` > `Full Screen`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the toolbars (although this is not fullscreen mode), you can do it by adding "?rm=minimal" right after "/edit", and it hides the toolbars.

Credit goes to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446449/google-sheet-embed-url-documentation

Comment: Credit goes to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446449/google-sheet-embed-url-documentation

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

```
<iframe height="300" 
src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uUuBK87eQMY4YiJG9Posro5Yx3lce5gdVxSmxjHs8iY/edit?usp=sharing&embedded=true&rm=demo" width="75%"></iframe>
```

Where the &rm=demo part seems to make it impossible to show the menu, and also makes the controls compact, so although it does not make it fullscreen, it is a step on the way.