# Embed only cells from Google Spreadsheet and not application header

Tags: google-sheets, querystring

When I embed a Google spreadsheet, I get cells in my page (and this is good). But I get also the application header with toolbars (and this is bad for me). See a test here: http://www.lucagiorcelli.it/test/fbapp/

I want to embed cells only, and not the Google Docs application header. How can I get such result?

I tried to add `&widget=false` to the URL but nothing happened.

Comment: Related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/15345/88163

Answer (score 3):

add this to your line
rm=minimal

example `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&rm=minimal#gid=53`

Resources

- [Google sheet embed URL documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23446449/)