# How to embed a Google Spreadsheet with just cells and a sheet list?

Tags: google-sheets

[This answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30644/embed-only-cells-from-google-spreadsheet-and-not-application-header) shows how to hide the UI and sheet list by appending `rm=minimal` to the URL.

Is there a way to hide the UI but not the sheet list?

I want to insert the spreadsheet on another page with an iframe. The top bar makes absolutely no sense in this scenario since nobody is going to edit the spreadsheet in that tiny iframe. But the sheet list is still a necessity to access the information.

Any way to have it?

Answer (score 4):

At this time adding `?rm=minimal` shows the spreadsheet grid and the sheets buttons and tabs at the bottom. Add it after `/edit` and before `#gid=`

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EnYwx2eMRDdN_DIkNk_UNicc3x-qQ0nnEH2ptZ0gL18/edit?rm=minimal#gid=210074931)

[image: Google Sheets displaying grid and sheets buttons and tabs]

Resources

- [Google sheet embed URL documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23446449/)